# Issue starting MongoDB service on Windows Server 2008

Tags: node.js, mongodb, iis, windows-server-2008, iisnode

The service was working fine until it suddenly crashed, and won't restart. Here is the log file:

```
2016-04-20T22:51:31.166-0400 I CONTROL  [serviceShutdown] got SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN request from Windows Service Control Manager, will terminate after current cmd ends
2016-04-20T22:51:31.179-0400 I FTDC     [serviceStopWorker] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I CONTROL  [serviceStopWorker] now exiting
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I NETWORK  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I NETWORK  [serviceStopWorker] closing listening socket: 516
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I NETWORK  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I NETWORK  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I NETWORK  [conn135] end connection 127.0.0.1:61587 (4 connections now open)
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I STORAGE  [serviceStopWorker] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I NETWORK  [conn137] end connection 127.0.0.1:61589 (4 connections now open)
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I NETWORK  [conn133] end connection 127.0.0.1:61585 (4 connections now open)
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I NETWORK  [conn134] end connection 127.0.0.1:61586 (4 connections now open)
2016-04-20T22:51:31.211-0400 I NETWORK  [conn136] end connection 127.0.0.1:61588 (4 connections now open)
2016-04-20T22:51:31.338-0400 I STORAGE  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2016-04-20T22:51:31.341-0400 I CONTROL  [serviceStopWorker] dbexit:  rc: 49
```

Anyone had a similar issue? I'm using IISnode to run mongo with a node server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another coworker had changed the path to the Mongo logfile in mongo.config. Halp I am Idiot